# Extract only values from JSON object in javascript without using a loop

Tags: javascript, json

is there a "Nice" way to get all the values out of a json object (I don't care about the keys) - just get the values into array, 
without using a loop ? 
(lang is Javascript)

Comment: Why don't you want a loop? Without a loop you can try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: Thanks, It's a little early for that - I guess in a few months this will be the right answer :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on how you define "loop".

You can extract the properties with `Object.keys` and then `map` them to their values.

… it's still essentially a loop under the hood though.

```js
var json = `{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
console.log(values);
```

With weaker browser support you could use the `values` method.

```js
var json = `{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.values(obj);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: thanks - that's what I was looking for. Obviously a loop will occur under the hood, just wanted the source to look smaller.

Comment: Object.values now has 94% browser support: https://caniuse.com/object-values

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for Object.values() function, just pass the object to the **values** method of Object as first param. That's it!

```
Object.values({something: 'lol'});
> ["lol"]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Recursively extract as text

**Yes, this is a loop** but the underlying methods you are calling such as `Object.values` or `arr.map` **are still loops**. I found this useful for extracting text out of a json object for full text search in particular and thought it useful as I came here initially needing this but the answers only touched the surface as **json is recursive** in nature.

```
function textFromJson(json) {
    if (json === null || json === undefined) {
      return '';
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(json) && !Object.getPrototypeOf(json).isPrototypeOf(Object)) {
      return '' + json;
    }
    const obj = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(json)) {
        obj[key] = textFromJson(json[key]);
    }
    return Object.values(obj).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES2017 you have Object.values(). You can [polyfill it also](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries).

Only you need is transform JSON to JavaScript object and call Object.values(). The result is an array of values.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var result = Object.values(obj);
```

Comment: I guess it's not available yet... ?

Comment: This proposal  is at stage 4. If you use Typescript or Babel you can use it and transpilate your code to ES5 javascript.

Otherwise, if you include the polyfill you should able to use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a function to `JSON.parse`, it will be called each time a value is parsed:

```js
function get_values(json) {
   let values = []
   JSON.parse(json, (key,value)=>{ values.push(value) })
   return values
}
```

ex:

```js
get_values(`{"a":1, "b":[true, false], "c":3}`)
// returns a list of:
• 1
• true
• false
• [true, false]
• 3
• {a:1, b:[true, false], c:3}
```

Note: If you don't consider the full object to be a "value", just remove the last item.