# Formatting JSON to specific structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am generally new to JavaScript programming and front-end in generally so please don't judge me :), today I run into some tough problem and I don't how to solve so any help would be welcome. So here is the problem:

I have some JSON structure like on the [image: JSON Example] and it is normal javascript JSON, what I want to do is a format and switch elements in the array to the specific order, for example, let's say I have given this order of elements:

```
var jsonObject =[{"id":1,"name":"Marco0",
                  "age":0,"startDate":"1990-12-01T00:00:00",
                  "salary":333.2132,"currentRate":0.3}];

var order=["name","age","id","startDate","salary","currentRate"]
```

And i want to have something like this

```
var result=["Marco0","0","1","1990-12-01T00:00:00,....]
```

so the result corresponds to the order that was asked for and to be an array of value. I have also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221672/extract-only-values-from-json-object-in-javascript-without-using-a-loop) and that is the only partial answer.

Comment: Look at a snippet of jsonObject and the image.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object. JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While having an array, you could map the array and map the wanted keys/values for a new array.

```js
var object = [{ id: 1, name: "Marco0", age: 0, startDate: "1990-12-01T00:00:00", salary: 333.2132, currentRate: 0.3 }],
    order = ["name", "age", "id", "startDate", "salary", "currentRate"],
    result = object.map(o => order.map(k => o[k]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yep, this works like charm tnx Nina, Vielen Dank!! Can you recommend me good book for JS

Comment: thanks, sorry no book advice, but checking questions and answerd could help a bit.