# How to detect if a variable is a pure javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

I have a function I need to pass an object to. I use `typeof` operator to make a check before processing. But looking at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), it appears that **many javascript instances, such as array or regex, are typed as Objects**.

I need my argument to be a pure object (like this : `{key: value, . . .}`).

Is their any way I can check if a variable is pure object, without having to run specific test for each Object instance, like `Array.isArray()` ?

Comment: Have a look at [this extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322968/1048572) about what makes up a plain object. "*I need my argument to be a pure object*" - why? Your function should not need to care.

Comment: Would `Boolean(obj) && obj.constructor === Object` be good enough for you, knowing that even objects that are instances of any class wouldn’t be matched?

Comment: how about `Object.getPrototypeOf(variable) === Object.prototype`

Comment: @Bergi False!  What if you need to distinguish between a plain javascript object, and things like HTMLElement, SVGElement, a Date object, a Node object, etc... "Your function should not need to care" is a very judgmental statement, considering that your contract may specify, "If the argument is a plain object, do X, otherwise do Y"!

Comment: @Michael Yes, I judge that a good API contract should not look like that, distinguishing things by the plain-ness of an object is a bad idea. Do you have an actual use case? If you want to find a `HTMLElement` (etc), you can use `instanceof`. The "plain object" is the `else` case.

Comment: There are legitimate uses for this. For example, when processing data for `XMLHttpRequest`/`fetch`, I wanted to convert pure objects into JSON without interfering with other types (FormData, etc.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of finding constructor name to check if variable is pure javascript Object or not

As per MDN,

> All objects (with the exception of objects created with
> Object.create(null)) will have a constructor property. Objects created
> without the explicit use of a constructor function (i.e. the object
> and array literals) will have a constructor property that points to
> the Fundamental Object constructor type for that object.

Please refer this link for more details on constructor property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

```js
var x = {a:1,b:2};
var y = [1,2,3];

console.log(x.constructor.name === "Object")//x.constructor.name is Object
console.log(y.constructor.name === "Object")//y.constructor.name is Array
```

Comment: this fails for values like `{constructor: 1}`

Answer (score 13):

You can check prototypes:

```js
function isPureObject(input) {
  return null !== input && 
    typeof input === 'object' &&
    Object.getPrototypeOf(input).isPrototypeOf(Object);
}

console.log(isPureObject({}));               // true
console.log(isPureObject(new Object()));     // true
console.log(isPureObject(undefined));        // false
console.log(isPureObject(null));             // false
console.log(isPureObject(1));                // false
console.log(isPureObject('a'));              // false
console.log(isPureObject(false));            // false
console.log(isPureObject([]));               // false
console.log(isPureObject(new Array()));      // false
console.log(isPureObject(() => {}));         // false
console.log(isPureObject(function () {}));   // false
console.log(isPureObject(new Date()));       // false
console.log(isPureObject(new RegExp()));     // false
```

Comment: I found this very useful @falinksy to aid in recursive walking along object properties

Comment: Here's what I ended up with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221672/extract-only-values-from-json-object-in-javascript-without-using-a-loop/59791420#59791420

Comment: `function  myFunction (){ /* ... */ }` test it `isPureObject(myFunction)` and will return `true`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check for "normal" pure objects (the ones created by `{...}`, `JSON.parse(...)`, etc.), then this function will work

```
function is_pure_object(val) {
   return val ? Object.getPrototypeOf(val)==Object.prototype : false
}
```

If you also need to handle objects *without a prototype* (very rare, only created by `Object.create(null)`), then you need to do an additional check:

```js
function is_pure_object2(val) {
   if (!val)
      return false
   let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(val)
   return proto == Object.prototype || proto == null
}
```

Notes about other solutions:

- Checking `val.constructor` is not reliable:

  - fails on values like `{constructor: 1}`
  - fails on `Object.create(null)`
  - error if `Object.prototype.constructor` is modified
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(val).isPrototypeOf(Object)` is also not ideal:

  - error on `Object.create(null)`
  - error if `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf` is modified

(`Object.prototype` being modified is unlikely, but I've dealt with it before)

Answer (score 2):

the shortest version

```js
const isObj = o => o?.constructor === Object;
```

found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61684890/7138254

Answer (score 0):

Detection of a plain object is a bit problematic because of the definition of "plain" or "pure". I use the following method to detect plain objects. I never use `x instanceof NodeList` type validations because they do not work on cross-frame situations. (each window or frame has its own instance)

I think this is the simplest and most effective way of detecting plain objects.

```js
function isPlainObject(o) {    
    var c = Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == '[object Object]'
        && o.constructor && o.constructor.name=="Object";
    return c === true;
}

function myTestFunction(){
/* ... */
}

class myTestClass{
/* ... */
}
        
console.log( isPlainObject({"a":1,"b":2}) ); //true
console.log( isPlainObject({}) ); //true
console.log( isPlainObject(null) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject("my string") ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject("") ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject([1,2,3]) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(document.querySelectorAll("*")) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(new RegExp(/[a-z]+/)) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(myTestFunction) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(new myTestFunction()) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(myTestClass) ); //false
console.log( isPlainObject(new myTestClass()) ); //false
```

Comment: `return c === true ? true : false;` can be simplified to just `return c === true;`

Comment: @flinsky during some tests on many browsers I noticed it sometimes return undefined or null instead of false when null and undefined values tested. So I added it to make sure it only returns true or false. And yes `return c === true`  is a better way. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: also using this condition `typeof o === 'object'` is a little bit redundant in the context of your implementation (as soon as you're relying on the `.toString` implementation) see more in https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Comment: @fallinsky it is for to make the evaluation more efficient. Non-object values will immediately return false after first evaluation. The following checks are more expansive.

Comment: Just keep in mind that **in general**, premature optimization is not something you should strive for by default. Unless you explicitly make (ideally) real measures for a more or less known or expected data set (or at least know the nature or restrictions for the data) - you don't really know what will be really more efficient. For example, consider executing this function for a set of 1000000 arrays or just `null` - this `typeof o === 'object'` will result in 1000000 unnecessary checks.

Answer (score -1):

Using the lodash library, you can achieve this with the following function:

```
const isPureObject = _.isPlainObject({ foo: 'Zebra' });
expect(isPureObject).to.be.true;
    
const isMapPureObject = _.isPlainObject(new Map());
expect(isMapPureObject).to.be.false;
```

The official docs can be found [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isPlainObject).